# Type 'key' cannot be used to index type 'P', when key is keyof 'PS' which is subset of 'P'

Tags: typescript

typescript claims for error when actually I claim this should not be an error and a limitation of typescript in the understanding of my case, or maybe I'm not writing it right?

here we declare interface `Feature` which uses 2 generics, P which will represent props and PS which represents pre-parsed props. parsed props keys is always subset of props keys.

```js
export type Feature<
    P extends any,
    PS extends { [key in keyof P]?: any } = {}, // all keys in PS must be in P
    > = {
    props: P;
    parseProps?: {
        [key in keyof PS]: (prop: P[key]) => PS[key]; 
                                //^ this is error when it should not be error
                                //  key in PS must be also in P, so i can use key to index P, but this is error
    };
};

// just example for reference, this is not required to understand the question
// this example working and the types are correct, but we have error in the declaretion of type `Feature`
const feature1:Feature<{age:number,somethingElse:any},{age:string}> = {
    props: {
        age: 1,
        somethingElse:"bla"
    },
    parseProps: {
        age: (age) => age.toString()
            //^ age:number as declared in P    ^ return type of type 'string' as declared in PS
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PS` may have more keys than `P` so `keyof PS` is broader than `keyof P`.

Eliminate the potential extra keys in `keyof PS` to match the union `keyof P`:

```
/**
 * Example: 
 * P = {age:number,somethingElse:any}
 * PS = {age:string}
 * 
 * Inner Exclude = Exclude<'age' | 'somethingElse, 'age'> = 'somethingElse';
 * Outer Exclude = Exclude<'age' | 'somethingElse, 'somethingElse'> = 'age' = keyof P ∩ keyof PS;
 */
type PickValidKeys<P, PS> = Exclude<keyof P, Exclude<keyof P, keyof PS>>

export type Feature<
    P extends Record<string, any>,
    PS extends Partial<{ [key in keyof P]: any }>, // all keys in PS must be in P
> = {
    props: P;
    parseProps?: {
        [key in PickValidKeys<P, PS>]: (prop: P[key]) => PS[key]; 
    };
};

const feature1:Feature<{age:number,somethingElse:any},{age:string}> = {
    props: {
        age: 1,
        somethingElse:"bla"
    },
    parseProps: {
        age: (age: number) => age.toString(),
    }
}
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhFgCgAIWhRAHgQwLYAcA2BTAXNKWaABWgF5oBvZAczwDsBXVAI2wCcAaAZwHtVsAFwAWAS3o14mbnmT0AngF9CcYgGVyVWnm6D24msphwV0AJL16HBIgDGmRgBNsmpPafYAPAHJt36AA+0N58AiIGUjKcwX4AfJoh-EJiEpHY3gDcpgDyjILWbg7OrnZFXr50-kGJYSmS0tjRNckRDd7xFBXpmgDW2PK8AGYk0ICURNB9A8PqWcbAUILy6C7EorY9AGrImKKOANL93J7E0eodNu7OnpNDJNGFHtf9tycTz9NqsbFQUNiI6Lx2IJoItltAAGLYZCCRjsLyEaCI0h-fL0RzcaAAJWwtkBjk8un0EmicnksU4CKRGhR2DRGOIyCBom2nko0AA2pNoOI3lMSABdfCk6CKcnQYDAaDbTC8jE89TQVCMXTQNjc+gkKDnSiU6Dodi8dDcfDEWaIxHoRkyYgGo0AfnwOpg5pdnP66pIa02212B3kR1eZ0F0AAFPrDSa3fJ+QBKcjxdRR-kZAjOxGKWYZn6QXH0FWDKEwuEARlwkOhsK81DouCYrA4PCS4VSDVwpMUnGrOj0BlFmidLvDRsdupd2nwxYpaZd0FCLRbMlwACIWJhkEvdR3dZb2NbbcaqKPzePQye62x2HGyPFtAA6QS8NQ9iQhmNTl1GRRAA)

Answer (score 1):

`PS extends { [key in keyof P]?: any }` means that `PS` has *at least* the keys of `P`, but can have more keys. So "key in PS must be also in P" is false.

See [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mb0dbw).

Comment: great demonstration, thanks. guess i understood it wrong